# DISTINCT IF MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to distinct item with certain condition. for example my table like this :

```
no| Device_id|total
090317016|167|147840
090317016|167|147840
090317014|167|155925
090317014|167|155925
090317013|167|188265
090317013|167|188265
090317010|167|170940
090317010|167|170940
NULL     |1672|3000
NULL     |1672|9000
NULL     |1672|12000
NULL     |1672|3000
```

I just want to distinct if no <> null, and no with null value keep display in table like this :

```
no| Device_id|total
090317016|167|147840
090317014|167|155925
090317013|167|188265
090317010|167|170940
NULL     |1672|3000
NULL     |1672|9000
NULL     |1672|12000
NULL     |1672|3000
```

UPDATE ISSUE:
If I select * from transaction where DeviceId = '167' it will appear :

`no| Device_id|total
090317016|167|147840
090317016|167|147840
090317014|167|155925
090317014|167|155925
090317013|167|188265
090317013|167|188265
090317010|167|170940
090317010|167|170940`

I wanna they be like this using distinct :

`no| Device_id|total
090317016|167|147840
090317014|167|155925
090317013|167|188265
090317010|167|170940`

but can I use distinct combine if clause  no is null ? 
then when I select deviceId = 1672 will be appear like this :

`no| Device_id|total
NULL     |1672|3000
NULL     |1672|9000
NULL     |1672|12000
NULL     |1672|3000`

so when display deviceId 1672, no distinct, but if i display DeviceId 167 using distinct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

union should do the trick:

```sql
select 
   distinct
   no,
   device_id,
   total
where 
   no is not null and 
   device_id = ?

union all
select 
    no,
   device_id,
   total
where 
  no is null and 
   device_id = ?
```

Comment: just add the same condition on both where clause or use the solution of Trx and add ` where device_id  = value`

Comment: thank you @cherif Odoo, you're my saviour :D.
but it won't solve it I use no is not null / is null. I change no = '' / no <>''

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT `no`, `Device_id`, `total` FROM `my_table` WHERE `no` IS NOT NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT `no`, `Device_id`, `total` FROM `my_table` WHERE `no` IS NULL
) t
```